How to Convert TTF to AutoCAD SHX Font?
I want to know how to convert TTF (TrueType Font) to AutoCAD SHX font file.
I have a deep understanding of TTF and can parse its binary data myself, but I don't know what the format of AutoCAD SHX files is.
I obtained a SHX file from somewhere, and the binary content looks like this:
41 75 74 6f 43 41 44 2d 38 36 20 73 68 61 70 65 73 20 31 2e 30 0d 0a 1a 01 20 01 20 01 20 01 20 87 20 35 31 31 30 20 04 65 04 63 03 65 03 21 03 60 02 09 0d 20 20 20 01 09 20 02 fd 06 fc 04 fe 20 fe 01 fc 20 fa fd fd fd ff fe 20 fe ff fe 20 fe 01 fe 20 fe 01 fe 04 fc 02 ff 02 20 02 ff 02 20 02 01 02 20 02 01 03 03 03 06 20 02 20 20 02 09 20 20 01 09 7f 20 17 20 20 20 02 09 ab ee 20 20 01 09 12 12 ee 12 20 20 02 09 20 dc 20 20 01 09 12 12 ee 12 20 20 02 09 92 ee 20 20 01 04 60 04 21 04 65 03 63 03 65 20 45 4f 46  


Does anyone know what its format is? (It's not the gis/SHX format)
The format of the answer I expect is as follows:
taking the TTFont in go language as an example,
type TableHeader struct {
    SFNTVersion   uint32
    NumTables     uint16
    SearchRange   uint16
    EntrySelector uint16
    RangeShift    uint16
}

type TableRecord struct {
    Tag      [4]byte
    CheckSum uint32
    Offset   uint32
    Length   uint32
}

type TTFont struct {
    TableHeader
    TableRecords []TableRecord
}

I would like to have a clear structural description. You can use any language or pseudocode to describe the format of the AutoCAD SHX font. thanks.

Maybe this repository can at least help to convert truetype commands to CAD compatible shapes (quadratic beziers need to be converted to polylines or arcs). Unfortunately, the SHX format spec is not well documented. Check also https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-DE941DB5-7044-433C-AA68-2A9AE98A5713
